# Target tvOS 8 (Apple TV 3rd) with Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, tvos

I’m try to target tvOS 8 (Apple TV 3rd) with Xcode 9. Unfortunately Xcode 9 minimum deployment target is 9. I can't find the SDKs for tvOS 8 or Xcode 8 in the internet. Any suggestions would be much appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

tvOS 8 does not exist, the first released version of tvOS was 9.0.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TvOS

AppleTv 4th generation with tvOS 9.0 was the first AppleTv with an AppStore, there is no way to create App for previous models.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop apps for versions of tvOS older than tvOS 9.0 or for versions of the Apple TV older than the 4th generation.